# Transpose DataFrame of 2 columns in R, in which 1 column has all the observations

Tags: r, dataframe, transpose

my data frame has in the first column repeated labels, and in the second column all the observations. Its like a data frame made of multiple stacked data frames

Something like this:

| Labels | Observations |
| --- | --- |
| A | x1a |
| B | x1b |
| C | x1c |
| A | x2a |
| B | x2b |
| C | x2c |
| A | x3a |
| B | x3b |
| C | x3c |

I need something like this

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| x1a | x1b | x1c |
| x2a | x2b | x2c |
| x3a | x3b | x3c |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using `tidy::pivot_wider` after creating a `unique` identifier for each `Label`:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(unique = row_number(), .by = Labels) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Labels, values_from = Observations) %>% select(-unique)

#   A     B     C    
#   <chr> <chr> <chr>
# 1 x1a   x1b   x1c  
# 2 x2a   x2b   x2c  
# 3 x3a   x3b   x3c
```

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes we forget simple base R functions. Eg this can be accomplished using `unstack`:

```
unstack(rev(df))
    A   B   C
1 x1a x1b x1c
2 x2a x2b x2c
3 x3a x3b x3c
```

or even:

```
unstack(df, Observations~Labels)
    A   B   C
1 x1a x1b x1c
2 x2a x2b x2c
3 x3a x3b x3c
```

---

```
data.frame(split(df$Observations, df$Labels))
    A   B   C
1 x1a x1b x1c
2 x2a x2b x2c
3 x3a x3b x3c
```